# Как сгенерировать список

Tags: c#, списки

Есть функция

```
var result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V1,
    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(device.Ip), 161),
    new OctetString("public"),
    new List<Variable> {
        new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.2.1.1.3.2")),
        new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.5.1.1.2.4")),
        new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.5.1.1.3.4"))
    },
    100);
```

Как мне сгенерировать переменную

```
new List<Variable> {
    new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.2.1.1.3.2")),
    new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.5.1.1.2.4")),
    new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.5.1.1.3.4"))
}
```

имея список OIDов

```
List<string> device.OIDs
```

?

Comment: `списокОидов.Select(x => new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(x)));`?

Comment: @AK `.ToList()`. Иначе будет `IEnumerable<Variable>`.

Comment: Ну да, я просто не понимаю, в чём сложность вопроса. Толи я не понимаю, чего хочет автор, толи автор только осваивает linq.

Comment: @A K Автор в принципе только начал осваивать c# и после питона очень дико видеть подобные конструкции))

Comment: В чём дикость? Я вот глядя на ваш код думаю "зачем понадобилось два раза обернуть строку?" - вы строку положили в ObjectIdentifier, а потом ещё раз - уже в Variable. Может надо было ещё пятнадцать классов-матрёшек сделать и говорить, что c# дикий? ;) Что-то мешало вашему Get принять одним из параметров `List<string>` вместо `new List<Variable>`? Или обернуть всего лишь один раз, если вам нужна семантика.

Comment: Это не мой метод, это библиотека SNMP https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib

Comment: Ага, почитал про их Get/Set, стало более понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то так:

```
void Main()
{
    var oidsList = new List<string>
    {
        "1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.2.1.1.3.2",
        "1.3.6.1.4.1.42019.3.2.2.5.1.1.2.4"
    };
    var result = oidsList.Select(x => new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(x))).ToList();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class ObjectIdentifier
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public ObjectIdentifier(string a)
    {
        this.MyProperty = a;
    }
}

public class Variable
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }

    public Variable(ObjectIdentifier b)
    {
        this.MyProperty = b.MyProperty;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас за IDE такая, что IL инструкции показывает?

Comment: @Anamnian, `LinqPad` какой-нибудь, это не IDE

Comment: @Anamnian О, это очень замечательная вещь - называется LinqPad! Я весьма рекомендую - это мой ежедневный инструмент наряду с Visual Studio. Маленький легковесный блокнотик в котором я рисую небольшие скетчи, а потом переношу в реальные проекты.

Comment: @Grundy ага, спасибо, недавно встретил упоминание о нем в одной статье на хабре, раздумывал поставить или нет. Сейчас точно поставлю, лень каждый раз ildasm.exe запускать.

Comment: `var result = oidsList.Select(x => new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(x))).ToList();`
Это работает. Т.е. сделал так:

`var result = Messenger.Get(VersionCode.V1,
                                    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(device.Ip), 161),
                                    new OctetString("public"),
                                    device.OIDs.Select(x => new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier(x))).ToList(),
                                    100);`

не получается победить местный редактор

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов потому что в комментариях у нас не принято писать код - либо в ответах, либо в вопросах. Ужасно неудобно же разбираться в форматировании в комментариях.